# Why won't this nested switch statement work? (C++)

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm having issues with this program. I'm trying to use a nested switch statement.

```
 void main()
{
int function_select, log_select, root_select ;
do
{
    cout << "Please select the function you would like to use \n 1 : Logarithm \n 2 : Root \n 0 : Quit" << endl;
    cin >> function_select;

    switch (function_select)// main menu
    {
    case 1:// log menu
    {
        cout << "Please select which logarithm function you would like to perform \n 1 : Common Log \n 2 : Natural Log \n 3 : Log Base n \n 0 : Back" << endl;
        switch (log_select)
        {
        case 1://common log
        {

        }
        break;
```

Sorry if it looks a little messy. I'm still pretty new to C++. There is more to this program, but i know the problem is in this section. When i run the program, i get an error stating that the variable `log_select` is being used without being initialized, even though I initialized it in the main program. Any suggestions that could fix this? And if you could explain why this doesn't work, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: _"even though I initialized it in the main program"_ You clearly didn't. Can you show where you initialized it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly *don't* initialize `log_select`, and you don't read any user input to it, either.

That's why you get an error: its value is unspecified (read: non-existent) and your attempt to evaluate it has undefined behaviour (read: don't do this).

I guess you forgot:

```
cin >> log_select;
```

---

To initialise those variables to `0`, you'd write:

```
int function_select = 0, log_select = 0, root_select = 0;
```

…though if you'd done that then you wouldn't have had a compiler error informing you about this bug! Sometimes failing to initialise variables is useful.

Comment: About five seconds after I posted this, i realized i forgot to have `log_select` input. I don't know what i was thinking! Thanks for the feedback though. I will make everything defaulted to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You don't read input into log_select before the switch statement which uses it.

Answer (score 1):

"Initialized" is different from "declared". You clearly declared that variable, but you didn't assign a value to it. Therefore you didn't initialize it.

Comment: It's declared and defined. It is not initialised. And neither of those terms are code so please don't use code formatting blocks to highlight them. Cheers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Damn. Haskell makes me do bad things...